# how to create a pulse train using anonymous function - Matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I have a pulse shape that is a function of t, call it h(t), that is in the form of:

```
h = @(t) function of t
```

I want to create a pulse train that is consisted of N pulses h(t).
I did this by:

```
for n=0:N-1
    comb = comb + h(t - n);
end
```

However, once I do that I can't change t in the train.
How can I create this train so that it will also be a function of t?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create a discrete pulse train as an array, or are you using symbolic math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make `comb` an anonymous function too. You can initialise it to some trivial function (i.e. it always outputs 0), and then repeatedly modify it. Since variables declared before an anonymous function declaration, including anonymous functions, are kind of "frozen" to the definition at that point this will work.

```
h = @(t) _______ % some function of 't'
comb = @(t) 0;

for n = 0:N-1
    comb = @(t) comb(t) + h(t - n);
end
```

We can test this with `h = @(t) sin(t)` and `N=3`:

```
>> comb(pi/2)
ans = 1.1242

>> h(pi/2) + h(pi/2-1) + h(pi/2-2)
ans = 1.1242
```

Note that just displaying `comb` can be a bit misleading, since information about the recursive definition is somewhat lost

```
disp(comb)
  @(t)comb(t)+h(t-n)
```